# Running a script that calls another script as an argument that in turn has arguments

Tags: python, function, arguments

I'm looking for the most efficient/simple way to run a script (we'll call it script1) with arguments that:

1. call one (only one) of several other scripts (as an argument to script1), which in turn:
2. has arguments on it that are given when script1 is run and are passed along to whichever script is being run based on the argument on script1...

For example, I'd like to run script1 which has arguments to call script2 which has arguments a and b:

script1.py ( script2 a b )

I've looked into functions and have read some people suggesting lambda but I'm fairly novice and want to learn and understand, not just be provided with an answer I don't understand...

Just wondering what some approaches are and am looking for generic examples of how to accomplish what I want so I can program it and understand it...

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: This isn't python based but I'd use xargs.

Comment: read the Python tutorial, it explains how you use functions and import scripts.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're having trouble with from the way you've phrased your question.  Can you post what you have so far, and ask about the part you're stuck on?

Comment: Thanks for the response, TokenMacGuy - I think part of the issue is that I'm working with this script in ArcMap (GIS software) and am having trouble passing arguments to some models I've built so I'm re-working it in Python...I'll keep plugging away!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your script (one Python program, let's call it `script1.py`) to call *another* script (another Python program) with the given arguments, you can write `script1.py` as:

```
import subprocess, sys

subprocess.call(sys.argv[1:])
```

`sys.argv` is a list that contains your program's name (use `print sys.argv[0]` and see that by yourself) and, after that, all the arguments passed to your program.

`sys.argv[1:]` means: the contents of the `sys.argv` list, starting from the second element (which has index 1) to the end of the list.

`subprocess.call` calls another program, and it accepts a list which contains the program to be executed and all its arguments.

Comment: While my knee-jerk response is that it is generally better to use the import statement or even the __ import __ function to achieve this, I admit that depending on the requirements it could be desirable to keep these as separate scripts.  (For example one of them might not be implemented in Python.)

Comment: Thanks Danilo - I'll use that as a starting point as it seems like a simple way to accomplish what I want to do here - as usual, there seems to be more than one way to do things in Python (which is a good thing)!